# How to get a certain sub_string in a sting using jquery

Tags: jquery, substr

I have a routine that produces id attributes on a  tag -- anywhere from [1] to [??]

I want to be able to evaluate the string and extract the id ordinal using jquery.

Here is my sample markup:

```
<div id="abc[1]"></div>
<div id="abc[15]"></div>
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
var n1=???.indexOf("[");
var n2=???.indexOf("]");
var theID = $('#???').substr(n1,n2);
```

But I am wondering how to make it work as simply as possible.

I want `theID` to retrieve `1` or `15`, etc.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? you need number ??

Comment: sorry @TusharGupta -- see my OQ revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var n = $(el).attr('id');
var theID = n.replace('abc[', '').replace(']', '');
```

Comment: yes, I like this better @TusharGupta. For some reason ('cause I'm an older coder) I struggle deciphering regex's. I like to be able to see the text in plain sight...

Comment: Thanks @TusharGupta. This did what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with native js regexes.

```
var n=jQuery(element).attr('id');
var bracketedarray=n.match(/\[\d+\]/g);
// will return, for example [["15"]]
var thenumber=bracketedarray[0].replace(/\[|\]/g,'');
// will return, "15"
```

Comment: Thank you @amenadiel. I elected to use the string.replace() method. I am quiet sure yours will work as well.